# Use if condition when joining subquery

Tags: mysql

I need that in the following query if the `Events.Type` field is equal to 1 that the part of the query with XXXXX be like this:

```
ON Stages.ID = Abandonments.IDstage
```

And in case it is 2 the Events.Type that the part of the query with XXXXX be like this:

```
ON Stages.ID > Abandonments.IDstage
```

QUERY

```
SELECT
*,
  Events.Type
FROM Participants
  INNER JOIN Times
    ON Participants.ID = Times.IDparticipant
  INNER JOIN Events
    ON Events.ID = Participants.IDevent
    AND Events.ID = Times.IDevent
  INNER JOIN Stages
    ON Events.ID = Stages.IDevent
    AND Stages.ID = Times.IDstage
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
      Retired.ID,
      Retired.IDstage,
      Retired.IDparticipant,
      Retired.IDevent
    FROM Retired) Abandonments
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    AND Participants.ID = Abandonments.IDparticipant
    AND Events.ID = Abandonments.IDevent
WHERE Times.IDevent = 31
AND Times.IDstage = 156
ORDER BY Participants.ID
```

Thanks

Comment: What research have you tried already? Why didn't it work as expected?

Comment: Now I have the if condition in my PHP code, so I'm duplicating SQL queries.  I do not know how to do it directly with MySQL.

Comment: So you can read the MySQL developers manual and search Stack Overflow for similar questions. You will find a solution. `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query has lots of `X` in it and doesn't display the qualifier you are trying to build, so I don't quite know the intention you are trying to reach here.

However, you describe the solution in your question.

thus:

```
ON ((Stages.ID = Abandonments.IDstage AND Events.Type = 1) OR 
   (Stages.ID > Abandonments.IDstage AND Events.Type = 2))
```

If neither of these defined arguments are true (say `Events.Type = 3`) then you would need to add a qualifier or a false return to exclude this whole `JOIN`

```
ON ((Stages.ID = Abandonments.IDstage AND Events.Type = 1) OR 
   (Stages.ID > Abandonments.IDstage AND Events.Type = 2)) OR 2=1
```